# How to read that function declaration

Tags: rust

The following snippet is from:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold

I understand that the generic type `F` is a callable that implements `FnMut` and takes two args: `B` and `Self::Item`, which is the item the iterator iterates over and the return type of this callable is `B`. My question is with regards to `B`'s type. It is not specified, no constrains are described. Am I to understand that it can be any type?

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are correct. So long as the type you give for `init: B` is consistent with whatever you pass to `f: F` then `B` is otherwise unconstrained here (aside from the implicit `Sized` requirement).

By "consistent with", I just mean that the `B` in `FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B` is the same type as whatever you pass as `init`.

For example

```rust
fn unsigned_adder(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a + b
}

some_u32_iterator.fold(0_i32, unsigned_adder);
```

is not consistent, because the function is expecting `B` to be a `u32`, but you've given a `i32` as `init`. Change to

```rust
some_u32_iterator.fold(0_u32, unsigned_adder);
```

and this is consistent.

(N.B. in the real world, type inference would sort you out in this example if you didn't put type suffixes on the int literals, but this is just to illustrate the point)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I have a question though. You are saying:
"So long as the type you give for init: B is consistent with whatever you pass to f: F". What do you mean by B being consistent?

Comment: @DeborahC I've updated with clarification

Comment: so basically that type cannot be really any type but a very specific type. If we look at the declaration of this fold function, B must by Self::Item. Is that correct?

Comment: @DeborahC No, it can be anything, it just needs to match the first argument to `f`. The first argument to `f` can be anything, but the second must be `Self::Item`

Comment: can you please show example where B is of different type then Self::Item? Because for the moment, I believe that B must be of type Self::Item.

Comment: OK, I got it, you can fold it to your own custom type as long as you specify it as an arg. Thanks.